# Window not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, window, onload

I am running a local server as shown and when I load it, it says "window not defined" what could be the problem here? I am waiting till it loads my index.html file and calling a callback to it.

```
module.exports=function(){
 //require the express module to use it in the app
 var express=require('express');
 //create an express app, fire the express function
 //to be able to use the methods in express
 var app=express();
app.listen(3000);
app.get('/', function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html',function(){
  window.onload=function(){
    alert('webpage loaded');

    }
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: I looked at the browser and it says window{onload:null }

Comment: @andrewL the title sounds promising but the question isnt really related (there is a gpod explanation of this case in PHP but I'm unable to find it)

Answer (score 4):

Your javascript runs *on the server*. The server has no `window` property. Add clientside code to your html, so it will be sent to the client by the nodejs' javascript and then it can execute on the client:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() { /*...*/ };
</script>
```

[Read on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Yes but I am loading an html page into my browser?

Comment: I have included the script file in my html